# How to pass returned public object from loaded JavaScript file into callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, public-method, dynamic-script-loading

I have a JavaScript file, which returns public methods. This JavaScript file I am not loading at the beginning, but preloading only when it's needed. Example:

```
(function () {
  // Some privat vars and functions
  var something = 'Something goes well!';

  function doSomething() {
    console.log(something);
  }  

  return {
    doSomething: doSomething,
    doAnotherThings: doAnotherThing
  }
})();
```

I have built a function with jQuery, to preload my JavaScript file when I really need to do so. Here's a function:

```
function load(file, callback) {
  var head = $("html").closest("head"),
      tag = $("<script />", {
        type: "text/javascript"
      });

  tag.on("load", callback);
  tag.attr("src", file);

  head.append(tag);
}
```

My question is **how do I pass returned public object from just loaded script into callback as an argument**? As I wish to use those public methods as soon as they are available…

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event when you load the file and then make the callback functions listen to that custom event.

You can use jQuery trigger method - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

If your already using jQuery, you could use the built in $.fn.get which takes a callback to fire on load success: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

(though maybe you wanted to roll your own load function instead?)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the returned value of the anonymous `function` to a variable. You will then be able to use it within your `callback` `function`, e.g.

```
var loaded = (function () {
    return {
        foo: function () {

        }
    };
})();
```

Within your `callback` `function` you could then just use `loaded.foo`.

As you're using jQuery I would recommend using [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to get the JS file. This would make the code simpler for you, i.e.

```
function load(file, callback) {
    $.getScript(file, callback);
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
load('js/test.js', function () {
    console.log(loaded.foo());
});
```